# Jquery Droppable into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, droppable

I am trying to use droppable jquery and grab each of the item and put it into array, but it isn't working as intended.

Basic concept:

```
var array= [];
$("").droppable({
   drop: function( event, ui ) {
      array.push($(this).text());
....
```

Let's say I drop "Chocolate", then I drop "Banana" into the droppable div above, some reason the array turns to be [Chocolate, ChocolateBanana]

I can't figure out how to get it to separate correctly to show [Chocolate, Banana].. any suggestions?

Comment: Why is your jQuery selector empty? `$("")`

Comment: Its just an example. Assume that it'll work and items are actually dropped into the droppable div. My issue is mainly the array not populated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

After you push, try clearing $(this).text()?

Comment: How exactly do you clear $(this).text()? The droppable items should still be visible, so whatever existed will be carry over into the array causing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, but not a "sexy" method.

Create a temporary integer and sum up all the length from previous array.. then use slice and remove the length of the sum. Then PUSH to the array.

Now I can move on and figure sorting issue.. probably yet another temporary variable array.

Comment: If there are any better suggestions, please let me know!